# c++ runtime error with concatenated message

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

I want to throw a error when loading a bitmap that include his path

```
ALLEGRO_BITMAP* bitmap;
bitmap_path
if(bitmap=al_load_bitmap(bitmap_path)==0){
   throw runtime_error("error loading bitmap from: '"<<bitmap_path<<"'");
};
//continue if no error
```

Comment: Could you try and reword the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `<<` operator to concatenate strings directly.

If `bitmap_path` is a `std:::string`, use the `+` operator instead:

```
throw runtime_error("error loading bitmap from: '" + bitmap_path + "'");
```

If `bitmap_path` is a `char*` instead, cast it, or the first string literal, to a temp `std::string` so you can use `+`:

```
throw runtime_error("error loading bitmap from: '" + string(bitmap_path) + "'");
```

```
throw runtime_error(string("error loading bitmap from: '") + bitmap_path + "'");
```

Otherwise, you can use `std::ostringstream` or equivalent to construct a temp `std::string` value:

```
ostringstream oss;
oss << "error loading bitmap from: '" << bitmap_path << "'";
throw runtime_error(oss.str());
```